# Django: Is it okay to generate session_key even when no user is logged in?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-sessions

Hi just wanna ask: Is it a good practice to generate Django's session_key (`sessionid` cookie) manually, outside Django's authentication layer?

I am implementing a `post hit/page views` and `post comment` mechanism, and I wanna use the `sessionid` to use for the `session` field in `PostHit` and `PostComment` models. Reason being, I don't wanna create an entire logic for generating custom-made session keys for this purpose since I think Django's `session_key` is pretty straightforward and is enough to cater the recording of web visitor sessions.

But I suddenly thought maybe the `sessionid` is appropriate only for logged-in users and shouldn't be generated for unauthenticated visitors. If it is not good anyway, do you have any better ways to generate session keys for both logged-in and anonymous visitors?

Much thanks!

**SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION OF session_key:**

```
class APIDetail__Post(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  queryset           = Post.objects.all().order_by('-publish_date')
  serializer_class   = PostSerializer
  lookup_field       = 'slug'
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

  def get_queryset(self):
    post_slug = self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['slug']
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=post_slug)
    if post:
        if post.published and post.approved:
            if not self.request.session.session_key:
                self.request.session.create()
                if not PostHit.objects.filter(post=post, session=self.request.session.session_key):
                    view = PostHit(
                        post=post,
                        ip=self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                        created=datetime.now(),
                        session=self.request.session.session_key)
                    view.save()
            else:
                if not PostHit.objects.filter(post=post, session=self.request.session.session_key):
                    view = PostHit(
                        post=post,
                        ip=self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                        created=datetime.now(),
                        session=self.request.session.session_key)
                    view.save()
    return self.queryset
```

Comment: Session IDs are something that can be used irrespective of an authentication. Don't confuse it with the Auth Token.

Comment: Thanks a heap @PankajSaini, got it! So I'll continue integrating session_keys for the said purpose then... and btw, I am using TokenAuthentication as my primary DRF Auth Class so I think everything is good from here.

Comment: @PankajSaini you should repost your comment as an answer (so Micheal can accept it).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks Bruno, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session IDs are something that can be used irrespective of an authentication. Don't confuse it with the Auth Token.